# MacBook Air: USB Hub Compatible with the MBA SuperDrive

Tags: usb, macbook, power, optical-drive, hub

A little background to those whom may think this Question too specific: The MacBook Air SuperDrive draws 1A vs 500mA of a normal USB device, and therefore you can't use a standard USB hub powered or unpowered because each port gets 500mA not 1A...

**Have any MacBook Air users found a USB hub which can accommodate the MBA SuperDrive and another peripheral?**

Answer (score 2):

I've tested a Targus Desktop USB 2.0 7-port hub, that specifically has two ports that support 1A current draw, and no luck.  I even tied both ports together (theoretically providing 2A) using a special USB y-cable from another DVD drive, and still no luck.

Comment: That sounds like they're specifically preventing you from using hubs, rather than a current limitation issue. (Sounds like a Apple control-freak thing).